# Inserting ad code after the first loop

Tags: php, adsense

How can I insert Google Ad code only after the first completed row after the `<br style="clear: both" />` has been inserted and then allow the loop to continue adding the `<br style="clear: both" />`, without the ad code, until complete.

This is the code that I am attempting to edit and it currently will process until all images have been displayed.  Each row is 4 images wide and after the fourth image it inserts `<br style="clear: both" />` and starts the next row.

```
    <?php if ($number_of_columns > 0 && empty($show_all_in_lightbox)): ?>
        <?php if ((($i + 1) % $number_of_columns) == 0 ): ?>
            <br style="clear: both" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here are the declarations

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<count($images); $i++):
       $image = $images[$i];
       $thumb_size = $storage->get_image_dimensions($image, $thumbnail_size_name);
       $style = isset($image->style) ? $image->style : null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $i represents the index in your array of images, you can add another if statement to check if it's the first row as shown below.

```
<?php if ($number_of_columns > 0 && empty($show_all_in_lightbox)): ?>
    <?php if ((($i + 1) % $number_of_columns) == 0 ): ?>
        <br style="clear: both" />
        <?php if (($i + 1) == $number_of_columns): ?>{insert your ad code}<?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```